# Shapes (1,) and () are not compatible on cond operator

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I want to skip some data that have specific labels (like if `label` >= 7 or other). My code is here:

```
true = tf.constant(True)
less_op = tf.less(label, tf.constant(delimiter))
label = tf.cast(
    tf.slice(record_bytes, [0], [label_bytes]), tf.int32)
tf.cond(less_op, lambda: true, lambda: true)
```

and on the 4th line I have error: `ValueError: Shapes (1,) and () are not compatible`. My assumption that it's caused by less_op (if I substitute it with `true` code works). Also I investigated that there is some problem with `label`: code `less_op = tf.less(tf.constant(1), tf.constant(delimiter))` works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tensorflow expects it to be of shape None or [] and not (1,).  It's weird behavior that should be fixed in my opionion because tf.less returns a tensor of shape (1,) and not shape ().

Change this:

```
tf.cond(less_op, lambda: true, lambda: true)
```

to this:

```
tf.cond(tf.reshape(less_op,[]), lambda: true, lambda: true)
```

Comment: tf.less returns same rank as input, so `sess.run(tf.less(5, 4))` has shape ()